# Getting the id from a div element and display it as alert

Tags: javascript, html, alert, identifier

Sorry for the easy question.Given the following html

```
<div id="Jessica">
  Alba.
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
window.onload= function()
{
  var hot= document.getElementById("Jessica");
  hot.onclick=function()
  {
   alert(hot);
   }
}
```

What should I put between the parenthesis to get the id displayed "Jessica"? Thanks.
I put "hot" but it is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `id` property.

```
window.onload= function()
{
  var hot= document.getElementById("Jessica");
  hot.onclick=function()
  {
     alert(hot.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: That uses a closure that might get the OP into trouble when adding multiple listeners. Better to use `this.id` and to set the value of *hot* to *null* to remove the closure. It results in a circular reference that is known to cause memory leaks in some browsers.

Comment: @RobG - there's no memory leak unless they intend to delete the DOM element later (and not clear the variable) and even then it wouldn't be significant unless they did this hundreds of times.  I wouldn't write it myself this way, but I chose to answer the question as simply as possible using the smallest change to the OP's own code.